# Issues with summary() function after reading model.rds in R

Tags: r, rds

I saved a svm() model in R using the function:

```
saveRDS(model2, "model2.RDS")
```

Then, I used the following to look at the 'summary' of the model:

```
model2 <-readRDS("model2.RDS")
summary(model2)
```

The output of the summary function is now totally different than how it used to be. What did I do wrong?

```
Length Class      Mode     
call                9  -none-     call     
type                1  -none-     numeric  
kernel              1  -none-     numeric  
cost                1  -none-     numeric  
degree              1  -none-     numeric  
gamma               1  -none-     numeric  
coef0               1  -none-     numeric  
nu                  1  -none-     numeric  
epsilon             1  -none-     numeric  
sparse              1  -none-     logical  
scaled          14088  -none-     logical  
x.scale             0  -none-     NULL     
y.scale             0  -none-     NULL     
nclasses            1  -none-     numeric  
levels              2  -none-     character
tot.nSV             1  -none-     numeric  
nSV                 2  -none-     numeric  
labels              2  -none-     numeric  
SV                  1  matrix.csr S4
```

It used to look like this:

```
Call:
svm.default(x = dtm_train_tfidf, y = train$gender, scale = "F", type = "C-classification", kernel = "linear", cost = 1, 
    cross = 10)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  linear 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  7.09824e-05 

Number of Support Vectors:  4278

 ( 2125 2153 )


Number of Classes:  2 

Levels: 
 0 1

10-fold cross-validation on training data:

Total Accuracy: 63.10417 
Single Accuracies:
 63.75 59.375 65 63.75 64.16667 63.95833 61.04167 63.54167 64.58333 61.875
```

Edit: Issue is solved. I should have loaded the library 'e1071' which was used to create the model that I tried to use in the summary() function.

Comment: you might need to load the library that you used to model the data to get the print method

Comment: @Kwiebes, try using str(model2) to see if you are using the model object instead of something else.

Comment: @user20650 Thank you so much! That solved the issue!!