# Reading R model from file.RDS saved on a VM instance

Tags: r

I created a few Spatial Error Models (using `spdep::errorsarlm`) on a GCP VM instance (running Ubuntu 16.04 and R 4.0) and saved them as binary files using `saveRDS`.

When I try to open on my local computer (macOS 10.14, R 3.6), I can't use `summary()` on them, nor can I print tables using `stargazer`. The output I get when using `summary(model)` is:

```r
> summary(sdem)
                Length Class  Mode     
type                 1 -none- character
etype                1 -none- character
lambda               1 -none- numeric  
coefficients         7 -none- numeric  
rest.se              7 -none- numeric  
LL                   1 -none- numeric  
s2                   1 -none- numeric  
SSE                  1 -none- numeric  
parameters           1 -none- numeric  
logLik_lm.model      1 logLik numeric  
AIC_lm.model         1 -none- numeric  
...
```

And:

```
> class(sdem)
[1] "Sarlm"
```

Why is this happening? From what I read in a related issue in [github.com/stan-dev/rstan](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/543), it might have something to do with the C++ compiler in each machine, but I don't really understand what's the problem or if there's some way to fix it. The models take too much time to estimate, so running and saving them again is not solution.

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545396/issues-with-summary-function-after-reading-model-rds-in-r) but even if I load `spdep` (or even all the spatial stats packages), `summary()` still doesn't work.

Comment: From the documentation for `errorsarlm`: "These functions are provided for compatibility with older versions of spdep only, and may be defunct as soon as the next release. The functions have been moved to the spatialreg package." Looks Like you should check out the `spatialreg` package and use the equivalent function provided there.

Comment: What is wrong with that summary output? It looks to be a list/dataframe type with nested content? Did you look into each element: `summary(sdem)$coefficients)`? Run `str(sdem)` for structure. Please show the actual `readRDS` line. Did you save the model object or summary of model?

Comment: Yes, that's true, I can perfectly see the model output by looking into its elements (e.g. `sdem$emixedImps`). I guess I'm being lazy and trying to use `stargazer`, but considering its support for spatial models is actually poor maybe it's just better to write my own code to print the table. I'll edit the Q when I have this code.

Comment: But I still don't understand why the output is different when saving it to an RDS file than when estimating it in the same computer. When doing the latter, Using `summary()` gives the usual output (the usual R table for any regression model). Just out of curiosity, why is it different when saving & loading the model in different computers? (If I save to RDS and load in the same computer, it works fine as long as I load the packages)